# Kirkland coffee beans are charged?

Tags: ground-coffee, paper-filter

Recently I noticed something interesting about Kirkland's coffee bean. After I ground the bean and dump on the paper filter, some fragments actually stuck to the wall of the filter - as if they were attracted/pulled by the wall and partially overcome the gravitational pull, instead of simply staying at the bottom.

I noticed this couple of month ago, over time, I observed and can confirm that: this did not happen with other brands of beans - so I do not think that this is caused by the paper filter or the grinder.

Not sure whether the ground bean is necessarily electronically charged, but that certainly can be a potential explanation.

Does anyone know what caused this?

Comment: Has this been consistent across grinds with kirkland beans or was this a one time phenomenon?

Comment: http://uk.businessinsider.com/heres-why-coffee-smells-so-good-2015-2 Might be helpful

Comment: That's true. I always assumed that it was their packaging. I never get that when going to a local store that packages their beans in paper.

Comment: This is just static and is a known phenomenon. It happens because of built up electricity between the grinder and the beans. Dry beans (darker roasts) will have more static. Quick hack: wet the back side of a spoon and stir the beans before grinding.

Answer (score 3):

Hi not likely to be a trait of kirkland beans or of packaging of the beans.
Static electricity can build up between the grinder and the beans. - you'll note that the beans will also stick to the sides of whatever receptical they get ground into.

Here's [one hack to fix this at the grinder stage](https://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-Hack-to-Remove-Static-in-the-Coffee-Grinder/) 
it used tiny amounts of moisture that likely reduce what's happening in the grinder that casuses static electricity: two materials rubbing against each other - and yes getting charged and repelling from each other.

Now maybe not all beans have this effect to teh same level based on moisture content - dunno - or perhaps its just humidity levels and grind sizes. But assuming for you it is just kirkland beans, and all other settings remain the same, you may want to try this hack and see if that sorts the issue.

Be keen to hear how your test goes.

m.c.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in static between bean brands is almost certainly different levels of moisture.

One of the biggest factors in static build-up is humidity. Moisture dissipates static, which is why you experience static build-up in (dry) winters but not (moist) summers. Add moisture to your beans and you'll reduce static (although I don't know the best method, and the moisture may cause other problems.)